# No Error in VB.net program during running but update command is not working in ACCESS Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, insert-update

No Error in VB.net program during running, but update command is not working in ACCESS Database. This is my first question, so for any mistake... sorry in advance.

```
 Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Try

        Dim dslno As String
        Dim wno As String
        Dim rno As String
        Dim qnotaken As String
        Dim qnosold As String
        Dim damage As String
        Dim cinform As String   

        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Shop Database.accdb")

        con.Open()

        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
            Dim values As String = ""

            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2

                dslno = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                wno = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                rno = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                qnotaken = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
                qnosold = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
                damage = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
                cinform = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value

                If wno = "" Then
                    wno = 0
                End If
                If rno = "" Then
                    rno = 0
                End If
                If qnotaken = "" Then
                    qnotaken = 0
                End If
                If damage = "" Then
                    damage = 0
                End If
                If qnosold = "" Then
                    qnosold = 0
                End If
                If cinform = "" Then
                    cinform = "No"
                End If

                Dim strcommandText As String = "UPDATE  PRODUCT SET  ProductName='" + DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "', WPrice = " + wno + ",RPrice=" + rno + ",Damage=" + damage + ",TakenQuantity=" + qnotaken + ",SoldQuantity=" + qnosold + ",CONTACTINFORM='" + cinform + "'"


                values = strcommandText + (" Where SlNo=" + dslno).ToString
                MsgBox(values)
                cmd.CommandText = values
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            Next i



        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Enter all Details")
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        con.Close()
    Finally
        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            MsgBox("Sucess")
            con.Close()


        End If
    End Try
```

I am sure you can help me, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: No idea, but try changing `ProductName='" + ` to `ProductName='" & `

Comment: Why you use ".ToString" in strcommandText + (" Where SlNo=" + dslno).ToString ? If you put here the final string "VALUES" before the "Execute" command, we can see if there is any error in the SQL Query.

Comment: At least use String.Format() to make it readeable.

Comment: You are still using `+` where you should be using `&`.  Otherwise, it's impossible to diagnose since you claim there isn't any errors.  You need to learn to use the debugger in these situations.

Comment: For INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE queries, the `ExecuteNonQuery` method returns the number of rows affected. Alter your code to capture that value {air code}`Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`{/air code} and then inspect its value. If it is zero then your query is executing; it's just not *doing* anything.

Comment: I checked it sir and it gives value 1

Comment: If `ExecuteNonQuery` returns `1` then one row has been updated. How are you inspecting the table to verify the update? If you have it open in Access try closing the table and re-opening it.

Answer (score 0):

You will save *so* much time debugging ugly little errors in your code if you start using parameterized queries:

```vb
cmd.CommandText = _
        "UPDATE [PRODUCT] SET " & _
            "ProductName=?, " & _
            "WPrice=?, " & _
            "RPrice=?, " & _
            "Damage=?, " & _
            "TakenQuantity=?, " & _
            "SoldQuantity=?, " & _
            "CONTACTINFORM=? " & _
        "WHERE SlNo=?"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", wno)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", rno)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", damage)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", qnotaken)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", qnosold)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cinform)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dslno)
Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Sorry Sir I change the code But no change. But their is two warning  1.Warning 1 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. Sujithshop
2.Warning 2 The referenced component 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs' could not be found.  Sujithshop

Comment: @user3005013 Sorry, but those warnings don't mean anything to me. Were you getting them when you used your old code?